# Auxlio em SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho o seguinte select:

```
SELECT CD_CLIENTE, 
       DT_ATUALIZACAO,  
  FROM TABELA
```

Que me Retorna o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu gostaria de selecionar apenas a ultima `DT_ATUALIZAÇÃO` de cada cliente, pensei em usar um `SELECT DISTINCT` mas não vai funcionar. Conseguem me auxiliar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu pensei no seguinte, como você quer a última atualização segundo a data então você quer a data de maior valor.

Então fiz o mesmo `SELECT` mas adicionei uma clausula `WHERE`que usa a função [MAX()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para buscar a data mais recente:

```
SELECT CD_CLIENTE, 
       DT_ATUALIZACAO,  
FROM 
   TBL_CLIENTES_SOFTWARE_HOUSE_ATUALIZACAO  t1
WHERE 
    t1.DT_ATUALIZACAO = (SELECT MAX(t2.DT_ATUALIZACAO) FROM TBL_CLIENTES_SOFTWARE_HOUSE_ATUALIZACAO  t2 WHERE t2.CD_CLIENTE = t1.CD_CLIENTE)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use da forma abaixo:

```
SELECT COD_CLIENTE,MAX(DT_ATUALIZACAO) FROM TABELA GROUP BY COD_CLIENTE;
```

Dependendo da situação, use o MIN() ao invés do MAX();

Espero ter ajudado! :)

Answer (score 1):

Usando `SELECT DISTINCT` você retornará apenas um único valor para cada cliente(`CD_CLIENTE`) caso ele se repita, mesmo assim, não iria solucionar seu problema.

Como deseja recuperar o código do cliente juntamente com a maior(`MAX()`) data de atualização. Você pode recuperar da seguinte forma.

```
SELECT CD_CLIENTE, 
       MAX(DT_ATUALIZACAO) 
FROM TABELA GROUP BY CD_CLIENTE
```